# Opening directory in java

Tags: java, file, directory, filepath

I want to read in a text file but I want to actually be able to open up the directory(wherever the program is ran) and navigate to wherever I want to a .txt file. How can I do this in java?

Comment: [JFileChooser?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: Or, for JavaFX: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html | If you specify your poison of choice (AWT, Java FX, etc, one can help you better.)

Comment: This is console based. So it's not a GUI. This is probably not possible from the console now that I'm thinking about it but I'd thought I ask.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a console-based user interface that allows the user to browse the file system?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The only UI part that I'd like is the navigation to a .txt file to read from. Does that make sense and is that possible?